# In Rails, how do I automatically load my parent object when the child object is loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, load, associations, parent, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.4.  How can I automatically load my parent object when I load the child object?  I have

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: :address_id, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy
```

But when I call

```
  @my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
  puts "address; #{@my_object.address} address_id: #{@my_object.address_id}"
```

The output is

```
address;  address_id: 6792
```

Meaning that no parent object was loaded, even though clearly there is an address record tied to it.  I would like it to be automatically loaded when my model is.  How can I do that?

**Edit:** In response to wishalizer's suggestion, I changed my models to

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    …
  belongs_to :address, inverse_of: :my_object
```

and

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :my_object, inverse_of: :address
```

but still got the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `includes' for #<MyObject:0x007fb7232415f8>):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `current_my_object'
  app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb:5:in `edit'
```

when applying the suggestion given.

Answer (score 0):

To include the parent relationship in the ActiveRecord Relation use [.includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) when you create the collection in the controller. `.includes` is symmetrically true, either from the parent to the child or from the child to the parent.

If you explicitly invoke `.includes`, and then you should be able to reference the parent from the child collection as you wish.

```
@my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id]).includes(:address)
```

**Model relationships required** [new section]

Append/insert `inverse_of` to your model relationship defs as such

```
    Class MyObject  
        belongs_to :address, {...your model rels..}, inverse_of: :my_object
        ...
    end
```

You must also create the symmetrical `inverse_of` in the related model

```
   Class Address
       has_many :my_objects, {...your model rels..}, inverse_of: :address
      ...
   end
```

Comment: I changed my line to what you had, “@my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id]).includes(:address)”, but got the error “NoMethodError (undefined method `includes' for #<MyObject:0x007f8981738d38>):”

Comment: Okay. I added a section to the answer about use of inverse_of

Comment: I don't have any validators, but even editing the code to include "inverse_of" results in teh same error.  I put my models in my question.

Comment: Not 'validators', I misspoke and I've corrected the text. If you have the relationships set up correctly and use inverse_of and .includes, you can access the parent or the child records. I can't really guess what else you have going on. The inclusion of "foreign key" in your MyObject model looks very strange there and incorrect. That might be messing things up. You could either post more error logs and I can try to help more, or if you'd rather wait to see if someone else shows up with an answer.

Comment: In my edit, I included my models exactly as you specified them (I didn't put anything for "{...your model rels..}" stuff).  Your code did not include "foreign keys" or "class" declarations, so neither did mine.  Got the error any way.  Also I put in the stack trace to the error.  Not sure how that would help but since your helping me out I wanted to put in the infromation that you asked for.

Comment: In the 'your keys' section you have to include whatever model relationships defs you need an APPEND :inverse_of. The undefined error on .includes means your relationships are not set up correctly. Your reluctance to post much code or error traces makes it impossible to say more. Good luck with this.

Comment: Hey the error stack trace I posted is all the error there is -- believe me I want to find a solution here.  What ohter logs are you looking for?  Maybe there's some Rails log setting I'm not enabling.  Regarding the "your keys" you mention, can you include that code in your answer?  I'm not making the connection on what I need to add here.

Comment: I think for anyone to help, we need to see more code including the actual model code that you are executing. The code snippet referencing my_object has no context. Is it controller code? Is the ID set in the hash? Pls post the code before and after the place the error is generated. I don't have enough to go on to make any more suggestions. Maybe post the schema to show which indexes are defined. The foreign_key declaration in the model snippet you posted is unusual. If the 2 models are related via primary key index, there is no need to declare the primary idx as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in to it.Correct me if i am getting wrong

MyObject.includes(:address).references(:address)

Answer (score 0):

> But when I call
>
> ```
> @my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
> puts "address; #{@my_object.address} address_id: #>{@my_object.address_id}"
> ```
>
> The output is
>
> ```
> address;  address_id: 6792
> ```

Invoking `@my_object.address` is, in fact, loading the address record. One possible case why `@my_object.address` is showing blank is probably that the `address` with `id=6792` doesn't exist.

And to correct Val Asensio's (wishalizer?) suggestion to fix the `NoMethodError`, move the `includes()` function to the correct position:

```
@my_object = MyObject.includes(:address).find(params[:id])
```